# Collapse all other divs when different div is expanded

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JS Code to slide DIVs up and down:

```
$(".desc_div").slideUp();
$(".open_div").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

how can i make it so when a second div is expanded the other open one will close?

http://jsfiddle.net/MaW35/

Comment: Might want to fix your fiddle so it loads jQuery.

Comment: .next(), gets the immediate child of `this` so if u have <br> or <span> you get br or span not the `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **.siblings()** - it picks all neighbours of element excluding itself.

```
$(".open_div").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow").siblings('.desc_div').slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/MaW35/7/

Comment: Also, this is better than simply adding a `$(".desc_div").slideUp();` before `$(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow");` in the original example, because it allows the boxes to be collapsed.
See http://jsfiddle.net/4YZG6/

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine:

```
$(".desc_div").slideUp();
$(".open_div").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow");
    $('.desc_div').hide()
    $(this).next(".desc_div").show()
  });
```